# CardView or MaterialTextView OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, materialcardview

I have cardview and material textview used inside LinearLayout layout like below

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_date"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:clipToPadding="true"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                            android:focusable="true">

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/editText_schedule_date"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="@color/transparent"
                            android:text="@string/date_post"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/textView_hint_upload"
                            android:theme="@style/editText_style"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>



                        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:clipToPadding="true"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                            android:id="@+id/editText_schedule_time"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/transparent"
                            android:hint="@string/time_post"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:inputType="time"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/textView_upload"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/textView_hint_upload"
                            android:theme="@style/editText_style"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
                    </LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to use it in my activity like below

```
private MaterialCardView card_date;
```

then on create like below

```
card_date = findViewById(R.id.card_date);
card_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("called","this card");
            }
        });
```

But its not working. I have tried textview onclick listener as well and that also not working. Let me know if anyone can help me for solve the puzzle. Thanks! Code outside this LinearLayout is working fine for same. Thanks!

Comment: can you share your activity code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was have used

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in textview which was causing issue. I have removed it and it has been solved.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `android:clickable="true"`

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
  android:id="@+id/card_date"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:clipToPadding="true"
  app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set `android:clickable="false"`

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:clickable="false"/>
```